# Accuracy of mysqldbcompare vs other tools like pt-table-checksum

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6, pt-table-checksum

I was curious to hear what everyone's experiences are with using mysqldbcompare vs pt-table-checksum( from Percona Toolkit ) to find the differences between two MySQL databases.

I have heard that pt-table-checksum is pretty dead-on accurate in figuring out if two DBs are different, but it looks like mysqldbcompare is able to show the actual row differences better and more clearly in its output.

However, how do we know whether mysqldbcompare is as accurate as pt-table-checksum or is it more/less ?

Thanks
IS

Answer (score 1):

It is a non goal of pt-table-checksum to show you the actual differences.  However, there is a companion tool [pt-table-synch](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html)  which can read the checksum table generated by pt-table-checksum.  It will take the bounds of chunks where master/slave checksums differ and then scan with in those to identify rows that don't match.

It will even generate replace statements ready to execute on the slave to get it in synch with the master.

Comment: Hi atxdba, I see, thanks, I will look into the pt-table-synch tool. Do you know how well it squares up against mysqldbcompare? It looks like it makes more sense to compare pt-table-synch vs mysqldbcompare then?

Comment: Sorry, no experience with mysqldbcompare